# Tetzaveh: (Re)creating the garments

Tags: beis-hamikdash, mishkan-tabernacle, tetzaveh, bigdei-kehunah

The Parshah of Tetzaveh deals greatly with how the kohanim (priests) and the kohen gadol (high priest) had to be dressed when entering the Mishkan (and in the case of the kohen gadol the inner sanctuary). In fact, the descriptions given in the Parshah are incredible precise and clear. One could actually (re)create the garments fairly accurate based upon the Torah descriptions. There is nothing vague in the instructions, I'd say.

As far as I understand (and I don't understand a single thing) the garments were to be worn exclusively in the Mishkan and possibly in the first and second temple, on Yom Kippur special requirements were to be met. 
What do our sages say regarding recreating the garments and wear them during communal service even though the third temple is still not around? Would it be disrespectful to dress in that particular way even though there no temple nor Mishkan arose in the present time?

Comment: Excellent question! I wonder: it’s forbidden to recreate the vessels, so perhaps that prohibition extends here?

Comment: Some of then explicitly contain Shaatnez

Comment: Interestingly recreating _ketoret_ is on _karet_ list, while the garments are missing. https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Keritot.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @donie "Would it be disrespectful to dress in that particular way even though there no temple nor Mishkan arose in the present time?"

Answer (score 2):

There is [an institute in Jerusalem](https://www.templeinstitute.org/about.htm) that seeks to recreate them to have them ready at some point in the future.

Otherwise, using them today is misguided. At the bare minimum, they contained a mix of wool and linen, which is prohibited to wear unless specifically commanded to do so, i.e. by priests in the Temple.

Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan notes this in his [commentary to Exodus 28:40](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=2&CHAPTER=28#C1721):

> "sash" -- Avnet in Hebrew. ... It was made of linen embroidered with colored wool (Yoma 12b; Yad, Kley HaMikdash 8:1). Although this is normally forbidden (Leviticus 19:19), it was permitted for the priestly garments.

(Every kohen wore this kind of sash. The kohen gadol had several additional garments that contained both wool and linen.)

More broadly, the Torah repeatedly stresses that there is exactly one Temple service. You can't offer sacrifices elsewhere. So too I think someone walking into a synagogue in Brooklyn and trying to make everything look exactly like the Temple in Jerusalem is very misguided.